# Appending Data Frames to a list in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have just started with R programming and have little or no knowledge on the same as you can say.
When I am trying to append data frames to a list.

I have the following code:

```
for(i in 1:NumberOfCoresUse)
{
  if(i != NumberOfCoresUse)
  {
    ListOfData <- list(unlist(ListOfData),RawTrainData[((i-1)*ApproximateRowsPerCore+1):(i*ApproximateRowsPerCore),])
  } else
  {
    ListOfData <- list(unlist(ListOfData),RawTrainData[((i-1)*ApproximateRowsPerCore+1):(MaxRecords),])
  }
}
```

When I am trying with the following, the data frame is perfectly added to the list:

```
ListOfData <- list(RawTrainData[((i-1)*ApproximateRowsPerCore+1):(i*ApproximateRowsPerCore),])
```

Or maybe when I am writing the following code, 2 data frames are added perfectly to the list:

```
ListOfData <- list(RawTrainData[((i-1)*ApproximateRowsPerCore+1):(i*ApproximateRowsPerCore),],RawTrainData[((i+1-1)*ApproximateRowsPerCore+1):((i+1)*ApproximateRowsPerCore),])
```

Comment: what is your question? E.g. show input and expected output data to illustrate your problem.

Comment: The idea is to run through the loop and append data frame to the list. Say the first data frame is 1:20, second being 21:30, third being 31:40. This is done so that I may pass this list to a parLapply and paralyze the code.

Comment: Ähhh simply this? `list(mtcars[1:20,], mtcars[21:30,], mtcars[31:40,])`

Comment: Can I append the same incrementally? like in a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for a loop, try to use `rep` and `split`

```
df <- data.frame(1, 1:10, sample(LETTERS[1:3], 10, replace = TRUE))
NumberOfCoresUse <- 3
split(df, sort(rep(1:NumberOfCoresUse, length.out=nrow(df))))
$`1`
  X1 X1.10 sample.LETTERS.1.3...10..replace...TRUE.
1  1     1                                        C
2  1     2                                        B
3  1     3                                        A
4  1     4                                        A

$`2`
  X1 X1.10 sample.LETTERS.1.3...10..replace...TRUE.
5  1     5                                        B
6  1     6                                        C
7  1     7                                        A

$`3`
   X1 X1.10 sample.LETTERS.1.3...10..replace...TRUE.
8   1     8                                        C
9   1     9                                        B
10  1    10                                        B
```

`?split` "The value returned from split is a list of vectors containing the values for the groups" Thus, you split the input dataframe into defined parts.

`?rep` is used here to define the grouping for split.